# Automatically expand C: drive in Explorer on Windows 7

Tags: windows, windows-explorer

Does anyone know how to get Windows Explorer to open the LEFT side in my C: drive with the folders in that drive showing.  NOT subfolders but only Parent folders.  I can do it so it opens it the right pane but not the left.

Answer (score 1):

1. Control Panel → Appearance and Personalization → Folder Options → General tab.  Check the "Automatically expand to current folder" option.
2. Then, open Explorer via a shortcut that runs the command:

   ```
   C:\Windows\Explorer.exe C:
   ```

Answer (score 0):

Sorry, I don't understand your question, but here is an attempt though:

If you click the arrow/+ left of the C:\ drive you will see the folders in C:.

You can change options regarding the file tree when you press ALT, then the menu Tools -> Advanced,
you will see options for it at the bottom, try to change these too see if it improves it for you...